# Mysql group by clause with multiple selects

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns in my product table -name and brand, Given is the data,

```
NAME               BRAND
'Ruby Axe Guitar', 'Guitar''s & Co'
'TV'             , 'LG'
```

When I tried this query its working fine,

```
select name,brand, sum(1000) as sum,'Test' as name1
from products
group by name,brand
```

but I got surprised even when I dont include brand in the `group by` clause the query is working fine..

```
select name,brand, sum(1000) as sum,'Test' as name1
from products
group by name
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: If you have multiple value in name then your query is not working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select ungrouped row without aggregate function - MySQL will give you random value. I guess you are lucky with this second query

Answer (score 0):

Because `NAME` is already unique with your data, so `GROUP BY NAME` is same as `GROUP BY NAME, OTHER_FIELD`.

`NAME` is unique, then the combination with any other column is unique too.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a lot less strict than it should be IMHO. According to the actual SQL specification, any non-grouped column needs an [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) in a query containing a `GROUP BY` clause.

MySQL will allow retrieving non-grouped columns without such aggregate functions, returning an arbitrary value. They have an [explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) of this choice in their documentation:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its intended as an ignored oversight.  TYPICALLY, you would be required to include any column that is a non-aggregate into the "GROUP BY" clause.  However, MySQL basically grabs the first entry for the column not part of the aggregate it encounters.

This could be ok, such as doing a query against a table/columns that you know wont change no matter how many records in the corresponding group by.  For example.  You want a list of customers and their total orders.  The orders table has a customer ID that joins to the customer table.  So, you can do a SUM( Orders.Amount ), yet still get customer ID, Name, Address, Phone.  Since the join is on a customer ID, the corresponding name, address, etc will never change and thus not be important within the group by.  Just group by a customer ID.

So, MySQL won't choke on you if you inadvertently leave out a column...